# How to check if a class is of type java.lang.Number

Tags: java

I'm being fed a `Class<?>` from a 3rd party .jar pertaining to a method's parameter type. I need to take different actions based on what this `Class<?>` actually is.

If it is anything that subclass `java.lang.Number` (such as `Integer`, or `BigDecimal`) I need to take a special course of action.

I can't use `instanceof`. And I'm afraid that if I use:

```
Class<?> someClass = getParameterTypeFrom3rdParty();
if(someClass == Number.class)
    // ...
```

Then it will execute if `Class<?>` is *only* a `Number`. How can I incorporate inheritance into the mix so I get all of `Number`'s subtypes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Number.class.isAssignableFrom(someClass);
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Wow! thanks John! Out of curiosity, does that work for interfaces too? I want to check if something is an impl of CharSequence (such as String, StringBuffer, etc.). It would be nice to be able to use CharSequence.class.isAssignableFrom(someClass)... thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) clearly state how it's used.

Comment: Note that this does not work if you try to test a class object for a primitive type. For example: `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)` is false.